# Cloning a Sprite Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, clone, sprite

I have a sprite that might be moved if there is no collision. For that I want to pass it along with its possible transition to a "Collision Detection" Method.

So, I am thinking about cloning it to a new object and adding the transition to its boundingbox/rect.

I couldn't get anywhere so far... here's what I have already tried:

```
1)

    CCSprite *futureSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[selSprite texture] rect:[selSprite textureRect]];

    CGPoint futurePos = ccpAdd(futureSprite.position, translation);
    futureSprite.position = futurePos;

2)
    CCSprite *futureSprite;

    futureSprite = selSprite;
    CGPoint futurePos = ccpAdd(futureSprite.position, translation);
    futureSprite.position = futurePos;
```

Should I follow any other path?

Thanks!

Comment: 1st method should give you a copy of the original sprite. Tell us what isn't working. PS: futureSprite's position will be 0,0 so adding the translation is unecessary, just assign translation to position.

Comment: Ok.. so how can I keep selSprite position inside futureSprite structure?

Comment: By the way... did you write or recommend any Cocos2d book for iOS? I have learned a bit of iOS/Objective-c/Xcode but it seems that dealing with cocos2d is a whole new world. Thanks!

Comment: Use selSprite.position then not futureSprite.position.

Comment: But I need to keep selSprite with its original information (used by another thread).

Comment: You're not changing selSprite, just take selSprite.position and apply it to futureSprite.position.

Comment: But if I do "CGPoint selSprite = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);" I will be changing selSprite... what I need is a Sprite with "future" x and y positions, but I also must keep its original position values.

Answer (score 1):

For copying the point of the original sprite to the copy:

```
CCSprite *futureSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:selSprite.texture
                                                rect:selSprite.textureRect];

// futureSprite has the same position as selSprite
futureSprite.position = selSprite.position;

// OR: use translation as position since futureSprite.position will be 0,0
futureSprite.position = translation;
```

No `ccpAdd` needed. Just assign the original sprite's position to the new sprite's position property.

Comment: Well.. I think we are missing some of the code. Translation has x and y offset to be applied to the original position. This is the function prototype: "(void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation". And translation comes from another touching function, its referenced like this "CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);"

Comment: That may be so but in this case you would add the translation to the selSprite.position and assign it to futureSprite.position - any other way wouldn't make any sense

Comment: But what if later on I need its original position? Should I add the translation to the selSprite.position, assign it to futureSprite.position and then remove the translation back to the selSprite?

Comment: What I am trying to to is this: I have a few pieces that can be moved by touch while pressed. I want the system to not let these pieces to overlap each other, detecting collisions among them.

Comment: So, for every movement there is a translation and before printing to the user I am checkin if there is any sprite intersection (predicting the future) and so the piece won't be moved.

Comment: The system almost works, but sometimes for some reason it is letting it to be moved and so, if I try to move this piece again it is already intersected and won't move anymore.

Comment: Tried something like this but didn't work either:         CCSprite *futureSprite;
        
        
        CGPoint futurePos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
        selSprite.position = futurePos;
        
        futureSprite = selSprite;
        
        CGPoint translationBack = translation;
        
        translationBack.x = - translationBack.x;
        translationBack.y = - translationBack.y;
        
        futurePos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translationBack);
        selSprite.position = futurePos;
        futurePos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);

Comment: Why do you assign selSprite to futureSprite? That invalidates everything you did to futureSprite up to this point.

Comment: This is what I was thinking: 1st offset selSprite. Copy the offset selSprite to the new futureSprite. 2nd backward selSprite to its original position. This way I would have 2 sprites. One with the original position (selSprite) and another with the probable future position (futureSprite).

Comment: If you can, please take a look the the whole GameScene file that I am working on: https://github.com/henriquesv/iOS_Tests/blob/master/GameScene.m

Comment: Friend, I have just made a new question (I think too many comments could make one else later a bit confused). Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882442/predicting-collision-before-it-happens-with-cocos2d