# Predicting collision before it happens with cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I thought about writing a new question, because there were too many comments and some other people could not get the proper idea of my doubt.

For this, I have posted my GameScene on Git: https://github.com/henriquesv/iOS_Tests/blob/master/GameScene.m

Summerizing:
This is a game where I have a few pipes connected and some pieces start already inside of them.
The user can touch each piece at a time and slide them through the tubes.

So, I have to be able to move each piece with a finger. The pieces cannot pass through the pipes (you can look at the piece of code where I check for some Areas). And each piece cannot overlap each other.. they are a barrier to each other.

What is the problem now?

The pipe areas are being respected (ok!), but the pieces are being overlapped by a few pixels and then they get stucked because on the next move they are already overlapped.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: We can't debug your app. Try to narrow down the actual problem and present it with corresponding code. I know this is difficult with physics-related issues, specifically because many such problems need creative solutions tailored to the specific game, and lots of tweaking. If you want to predict collisions that's going to be difficult but you can make some tests using ray casting. Both Box2D and Chipmunk provide corresponding methods for ray (and other) intersection tests.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the sprites from overlapping themselves (i.e. not colliding)?  If that is the case, you probably should put a real physics engine to stop them from contacting each other or (better) give you a callback when collision starts so you can do something about it.  Note that Box2d is well integrated with Cocos2d-x...you could have CCPhysicsSprite to do most of the heavy lifting...and it is not hard to learn.

Comment: Exacly! I will take a look at Box2d. Would you suggest any Box2D tutorial for the iOS? Thanks!

Comment: Guys, before trying something new, please help me out on this one. When I assign a CGSprite to another CGSprite, does it copy the other one structure or it only makes reference? Because I think that whenever I change one Sprite, the same happens to the other.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I thought I was copying all the content to the other object. But in the end I was messing with the same data on 2 different objects. What did I do? Created a new CCSprite from scratch:         CCSprite *futureSprite;
        futureSprite = [[CCSprite alloc]init];

        
        CGPoint futurePos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
        
        futureSprite.position = futurePos;
        
        futurePos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);